# How to access tableview custom cell from different Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have Viewcontroller**C** which has custom tableView cell and cell background colour is **Blue**. When I click logout Button from Viewcontroller**G** , I want Viewcontroller**C** tableView cell background colour should change to **Red**.

How to access Viewcontroller**C**  cell in Viewcontroller**G**  ?

```
protocol ChangeCellColor {
    func change()
}

import UIKit
class ViewControllerG : UIViewController {  
var delegate : ChangeCellColor?

@IBAction func logout_click(_ sender: Any) {
   delegate?.change()
}
}

import UIKit
class ViewControllerC : UIViewController {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .red
}
}
extension ViewControllerC : ChangeCellColor {

    func change() {
        cellColor = UIColor(red: 0.74, green: 0.74 , blue: 0.75 , alpha: 1.0 )
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Try explaining how viewControllerC is linked to viewControllerG so we can best help you answer this question. Depending on the type of link the answer could vary. For example does viewControllerC present viewControllerG. Or does viewControllerC push viewControllerG to the navigation stack. Or is there no link?

Comment: for changing Cell background colour you need to use custom delegate

Comment: In between ViewControllerC and G there  are another five view controllers they are connected through segue.

Comment: @SunilPrajapati how to use this custom delegate, can you explain?

Comment: @SwiftUser, In Answer section Mr.Bean answered

Comment: I tried Mr Bean answer , But when I segue back to ViewControllerC It still has blue colour content view , its not changed to Red.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Protocol & delegates to achieve your goal. Follow below steps  : **PS : This is untested version ---**

Edit : Since you told that there are 5 VC between these viewControllers, so check my edited answer...

```
protocol ChangeCellColor {
   func change() 
}

class ViewControllerG : UIViewController {

   var delegate : ChangeCellColor?

   @IBAction func btnActionLogout(_ sender: Any) {
      delegate?.change()
   }
}

class ViewControllerC : UIViewController {

  var cellColor : UIColor = .blue
  @IBOutlet var tableView : UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

       super.viewDidLoad()
       let vcG = ViewControllerG() // Or instantiate with SB
       vcG.delegate = self // Now maintain this object and eventually at the time of need you have to push the above object in the stack...
    }
}

extension ViewControllerC : ChangeCellColor {

   func change() {
      cellColor = .red
      tableView.reloadData()
   }
}

extension ViewControllerC : UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "") as? LocationCell else {return UITableViewCell() }
      cell.contentView.backgroundColor = cellColor
      return cell
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return 10
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  }

}
```

Comment: Its not working for me

Comment: You need to maintain the same object of ViewControllerG to which you have passed the delegate

Comment: its incomplete buddy

Comment: what is incomplete? what else shall I add?